# Mapping of elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to map the elements in a list based on mapping table in a dataframe. The list I have looks like this:

```
List1 = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('a','d'), ('b','c'), ('b','d')]
```

mapping table like this

```
mapping = {'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'ID': [1,2,3,2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(mapping)
```

what I am trying to achieve

```
Mappedlist = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,2), (2,3), (2,2)]
```

Comment: Is the "mapping table" a dictionary?  or named variables in the global namespace?

Comment: It's a pandas dataframe @piRSquared

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for the clarification. The question I was supposed to ask was all under one umbrella. But thanks to you for editing out my full question.

Comment: @Srini 1) Your edition gave to understand that you want the community to respond to another problem, and unfortunately / fortunately in SO you should only ask one question per post, so the button says "Ask Question", does not say "Ask Questions". 2) Always show what you have tried even if it does not work for the community to value your effort, not just say "give me code".

Comment: @Srini  3) Always give the necessary information, as you realized people assumed a lot of things about what they were "a", "b", etc. You must take a good time (IMHO half an hour) to ask the best question you can with a stress similar to the delivery of a job to a teacher or boss as the community also strives in the same way to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a better idea to iterate once in the `Mappedlist` instead of nested loops:

```
[(df['ID'].loc[df.name == x].item(), df['ID'].loc[df.name == y].item()) for (x, y) in List1]
# Result: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this nested list comprehension:

```
print([[df.loc[df['name'] == x, 'ID'].item() for x in i] for i in List1])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 2]]
```

To revise:

```
print([[df.loc[df['ID'] == x, 'name'].item() for x in i] for i in List1])
```

Output:

```
[['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['a','d'], ['b','c'], ['b','d']]
```

Comment: hi @U10-Forward, i just added another part to the question. If you could assist on that as well?

Comment: @Srini check my answer now

Comment: @Srini Try to replace `globals` with `locals`

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately doesn't work. My mapping table is in a data frame essentially 
Column1 has a, b, c, d
Column2 has 1,2,3,2

Comment: @Srini I edited it now check it please, accept and up-vote it if it works

Comment: @U10-Forward, I am getting an error for revision of list - "can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar". Not sure why python thinks I am inputting an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196581/discussion-between-srini-and-u10-forward).

Answer (score -1):

You can call variables instead of strings inside the list but make sure the variables should be before the List1

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 2

List1 = [(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d)]

print(List1)
```

**OutPut**

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: The `List1` is not `[(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d)]`, it is `[('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('a','d'), ('b','c'), ('b','d')]` - very different things. Hence unfortunately your solution can not address the concern.